# how do I prevent a product from being added to a cart based on the existing cart details on shop ware 6

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

Hello to be more descriptive of my question.

I am trying to prevent a product from being added to a cart if :

**product 1 with custom field "shipment". is added to cart**

and

**product 2 with custom field not "shipment" - I want to refuse entry into the cart because they don't have the same custom field shipment.**

currently I have been able to detect custom fields of each product added to cart by :

```
public function onLineItemAdded(AfterLineItemAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $lineItems = $event->getLineItems();

        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            $payload = $lineItem->getPayload();
            if (isset($payload['customFields'])) {
                $customFields = $payload['customFields'];
                $this->logger->info('Custom Fields:', $customFields);
            }
        }
      
    }
```

now I just wish to create a functionality which prevents product 2 from joining product 1 in the cart when they don't belong to the same custom field.

is this possible?